# Inconsistent behaviour when importing my own module in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I have created a module, it's sitting in its own folder with an `__init__.py` and four files that contain my classes.

When doing `from MyPackage import *` I'm getting the modules that I have written into the `__all__` statement in my `__init__.py` just as expected.

When doing `from MyPackage import ModuleX` I can import any module individually just fine.

When doing `import MyPackage` and then say `dir(MyPackage)` however, all I get is this:

```
['__all__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__']
```

My modules aren't shown and I can't access them using `MyPackage.ModuleX` either.

The only thing I have written into my `__init__.py` is the `__all__ = [ModuleX]` statement.

Why does the last statement not see my modules? Do I have to set some more configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__all__` determines what names are *exported* from that module. However in order to export them you would need to import them in the first place, which you haven't.

Comment: So I need to import all modules that are part of the package into my `__init__.py` to use them with the `import MyPackage` command even though they can be readily imported with the `from` keyword?